# Installing R 3.6 on Ubuntu disco 19.04

Tags: r

I have the new Ubuntu disco 19.04, and I followed the instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) to install the new R 3.6.

However, after installing the key and adding the repository through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/'
```

And running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.0-1cosmic) but 3.5.2-1build1 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.0-1cosmic) but 3.5.2-1build1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I could install R through

```
sudo apt install r-base
```

before adding the aforementioned repository, but version `3.5.2` is installed.

Does anyone have an idea how to install it without having to compile from source?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I followed the [same instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html), got R 3.5 as well.
Adding the repo's pubkey before running `apt update` got me R 3.6.

These should be the steps to install R 3.6 into a fresh Ubuntu 19.04:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base-dev
```

Changing the repository details allows installation onto other Ubuntu versions i.e. replace 'disco' with 'xenial' for Ubuntu 16.04.

Update Oct 2020: In the same vein (add repo, add repo keys, update, install), follow this [tutorial at thinkr.fr](https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/) by [Sébastien Rochette](https://rtask.thinkr.fr/consultants-r-experts/sebastien-rochette) to update Ubuntu to 20.* and R to 4.*
As a bonus, it comes with installation tips for dependencies of spatial packages.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @matt-paul! Be advised that the above solution is tested under Ubuntu 19;04 (disco) only, so one could run into different availability of R on other Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Thanks to @user2867078 for pointing out that r-base will also provide R 3.6. Installing r-base-dev provides additional packages required to [compile R packages from source](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html), which many users will need.

Comment: Works for 18 LTS by changing 'disco' to 'bionic'!

Comment: I get `W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ InRelease' is not signed.`

Comment: @samthebest I can reproduce your "NO_PUBKEY" error after deleting the GPG key, then adding the repo. I think your options are:


* Ignore the error and continue with the remaining three lines (add repo, apt update, install R).
* First add the pubkey, then add the repo.

I've also amended the code in the answer to first add the pubkey, then add the repo.

Comment: ```Ign:6 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ InRelease     
Err:7 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.225.241.21 443]
Hit:8 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/ Release' does not have a Release file.``` I got this Error

Comment: @amin Correct, the current contents of https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ do not show this release any more. It would be best to go with the latest R version that is available for your release (find your Ubuntu release codename with `lsb_release -a`).